# Imprimir caracteres especiais no console do windows

Tags: c, string

Como imprimir caracteres especiais como 'é' e 'ç' no console do windows (printf)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Há três formas de se utilizar esses caracteres especiais no windows :

1. Passando direto o código no printf: `printf("isto \x82"); //imprime isto é`

   (Esse código acima assume o CodePage 850 )
2. Criando uma função que utiliza a funcionalidade acima para imprimir os caracteres especiais
   um exemplo a função **oprintf** que está [disponível com a licensa LGPL](https://github.com/kyllopardiun/Stringpp)
3. Ou como o Giovani disse, usando  `setlocale`.

Nota: sugiro que não utilize system("PAUSE"); nem a biblioteca  quando não houver necessidade. (Estão no exemplo setlocale).

Comment: E qual código de página você está levando em consideração? o \x82 não é "é" em todos os CPs

Comment: 850, que me parece ser um dos mais comuns.

Comment: Talvez fosse bom complementar a resposta avisando isso, pois não dá pra contar com o CP ser sempre o "comum", mesmo que esta afirmação fosse verdadeira.

Comment: E de todo modo, o que é comum aqui pode não ser comum internacionalmente.

Comment: @Bacco atualizei a resposta para especificar isso.

Comment: @mgibsonbr, meu computador antigo usava o Windows em Dinamarquês, meu computador atual está com Windows em Inglês (Canadá). E no computado que tenho acesso (remoto) na faculdade do Brasil coincidentemente usam o mesmo codepage. Concordo que não é universal, mas me parece que funciona para boa parte dos casos.

Answer (score 3):

Conforme pode encontrar no site: http://linguagensdeprogramacao.wordpress.com/2011/07/16/resolvendo-problema-da-acentuacao-no-dev-c/

> Para resolver este problema basta você usar o comando de
>   regionalização do C para que não somente acentue as palavras
>   corretamente, mas que mostre datas e horas em português, por exemplo.
>
> Isto é feito usando o comando setlocale da biblioteca locale.h. Segue
>   um exemplo de código.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main(void)
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    printf("Alô mundo! \n\n");

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

----- Edit --------

Caso ainda tenha problema tenta alterar a fonte do Command:

[image: Command]

Comment: Obrigado, mas vou aceitar a outra por ter mais detalhes.